# How do I solve $\frac{-1}{3}|6−5x|+2<1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do i solve this problem?

$\frac{-1}{3}|6−5x|+2<1$

so far I took the 2 to the other side, multiplied both sides by -3 to cancel out the -1/3

leaving me with
$|6-5x|>3$

is this correct? by flipping the signs since i multiplied by a negative?but then what?

Comment: i mean subtracted the two to the other side. i got |6-5x|>3 after multiplying both sides by -3

Comment: Babak S. showed the solution to this problem in the above linked question.